# Explode Array and Show 4 random items at a time with Shuffle

Tags: php

I am trying to explode an array and then shuffle 4 items at a time so that each array appears in random order.

It half works but on refresh sometimes it shows only 2 or 3 arrays not 4. Is there an easy workaround for it?

Thanks in advance.

```
$siteswith = $row['siteswith']; 
$array = explode(',', $siteswith);  
shuffle($array);
foreach(array_slice($array, 0, 4) as $item ){

}
```

Comment: Would `array_chunk($array,4)` not work?

Comment: _"sometimes it shows only 2 or 3"_ Are you sure there are more than 2 or 3 items in the original list?

Comment: Seems there are not enough items in `$array` ... sometimes ... please provide input data

Comment: If you just wanna pick 4 random items from the array try `array_rand($array, 4)` ... but make sure that the `$array` holds at least 4 items, otherwise you'll receive an exception ... also be aware that shuffle will mutate your original array

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$array` does not have enough items that the slice function can "slice" from. Please check if your input string `$row['siteswith']` always provide 4 or more comma separated values.

Depending what the code is later used for, you could also use `array_rand()` to pick n random elements from the list

```
$siteswith = $row['siteswith']; 
$array = explode(',', $siteswith);  

foreach(array_rand($array, 4) as $item ){
   ...
}
```

This will also prevent mutating your origin array (other than array_shift will do) which avoids unexpected behaviour.

Please be aware that you'll receive an exception when the array size is smaller than the requested amount of random elements.